# Starting Hadoop Services using Command Line (CDH 5)

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

I know how to start services using Cloudera manager interface, but I prefer to know what is really happening behind the scene and not rely on "magic".

I read [this page](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-3-x/topics/cdh_ig_cdh_services_start.html#topic_27_1) but it does not give the desired information

I know there are some .sh files to be used but they seem to vary from version to version, and I'm using the latest as of today (5.3).

I would be grateful to have a list of service starting commands (specifically HDFS)

PS : Looks like somehow [Cloudera ditched the classic Apache scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24113166/where-are-the-start-stop-hadoop-hdfs-mapred-scripts-on-cdh5) (start-dfs.sh etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can figure this out by installing Cloudera's optional service packages.

These use the service command to start services instead of Cloudera Manager.

- hadoop-hdfs-namenode - for namenode
- hadoop-hdfs-secondarynamenode - for secondary namenode
- hadoop-hdfs-datanode - for datanode
- hadoop-hdfs-journalnode - for journalnode

You can see the CDH5.9 RPMs here:
http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/redhat/6/x86_64/cdh/5.9/RPMS/x86_64/

After you install them, you can look at the respective /etc/init.d/SERVICENAME
to understand how they are run (assuming you're comfortable looking at shell scripts).