# Init scripts missing under /etc/init.d/ after installing hadoop-cdh

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-cdh

In the documentation of Cloudera - "Deploying HDFS on a Cluster (Using Command Line)"

It's said that, to start the namenode service, type following command:

```
for x in `cd /etc/init.d ; ls hadoop-hdfs-*` ; do sudo service $x start ; done
```

The problems is, there is no item matching `hadoop-hdfs-*` name pattern under `/etc/init.d/` directory. I think there should be a hadoop-hdfs-namenode, isn't it?

Can someone tell me why hadoop-hdfs-namenode is missing? Is there any deployment steps I missed? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you look at the answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43165272/starting-hadoop-services-using-command-line-cdh-5/43380993#43380993

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the optional service packages on your install.  Try installing the hadoop-hdfs-namenode package.